# MATLAB Generate 3 dimensional dataset that include 4 normal pdfs of 4 classes

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, gaussian

How is possible to generate 3 dimensional dataset that include 4 normal pdfs of 4 classes? I'm using matlab, but i don't know how is possible to build datasets with this features

I can choice means and covariance matrix...
Now I know to solve this simple problem:

```
%mean
m1=[-3 2]';

%covariance matrix
S1=[1 0; 0 1];

N=500;

%to classify    
x1=[-2 2]';

X1 =mvnrnd(m1,S1,N)';

p11 = comp_gauss_dens_val(m1,S1,x1);


figure(1), plot(X1(1,:),X1(2,:),'r.');
figure(1), axis equal
figure(1), axis([-8 8 -8 8])

hold on

plot(x1(1),x1(2),'O');
```

comp_gauss_dens_val returns the value of the gaussian distribution at x.

Now p11 has the value of gaussian distribution in that point.

My problem is to extend this solution at the problem: "generate 3 dimensional dataset that include 4 normal pdfs of 4 classes and then classify some random points"

Comment: Can you expand the question a bit further? A sketch of what you are trying to do, if it is possible, will also help.

Comment: thanks! I'll try it because this is my first exercise about matlab and classification problems.
I think that this exercise require to make a dataset with four classes and three features ...(i think that three dimensional means three features) ...

and then classify some random points